# Nodejs express mandar un mail

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, email

Hola quiero mandar un correo pero cuando no puedo recibir los datos de usario no sé porque, cuando imprimo req.body me da undefinded. Alguien sabe si me falta algo?

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

// mi ruta por aquí

app.use('/', router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

console.log('Running at Port 3000');
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
  <div id="errormessage"></div>
  <form action="/contact" method="POST" role="form" class="contactForm">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" data-msg="Ingrese su nombre" />
        <div class="validation"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" id="email" placeholder="ejemplo@ejmplo.com" data-msg="Ingrese su email" />
        <div class="validation"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Razón por de su mensaje" data-msg="" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-msg="Mensaej" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
router.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
  //console.log(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  console.log(req.body);
  const {
    name,
    mail,
    message
  } = req.body;

  //console.log(token);

  const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  const msg = {
    to: 'support@trustfund.com.mx',
    from: mail,
    subject: 'Mensaje de web Trustfund',
    text: 'Gracias por tu confianza.',
    html: '<div class="card" style="width:400px">' +
      '<div class="card-body">' +
      '<h4 class="card-title">Mensaje de:' + name + '</h4>' +
      '<p class="card-text">' + message + '</p>' +
      '<p class="card-text">mail:' + mail + '</p>' +
      '' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>',
  };
  sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/successmsn.html'));
  });

});
```

en terminal me devuelve esto

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `name` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

Comment: Debes usar un parser para el `body`. Si usas Express 4.16 o superior puedes hacerlo así: `app.use(express.json());` además puedes agregar `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));`, ambas lineas las debes poner antes de tus rutas. Prueba y comentas. Saludos